# Cannot get interface from different process via ROT

Tags: interface, com, interop, marshalling

my app is an .exe, it registers itself to ROT.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[ProgId("My.App")]
public class MyApp
{
    public Interop_MyApp.IXXX XXX
    {
        get { return XXXImpl.Instance; } // -> Instance is derived from Interop_MyApp.IXXX, and static
    }

    public MyApp() { }
};
```

I start the .exe above, it's running.

Then I start an other .exe, which tries to get the XXX.

```
        object o = Marshal.GetActiveObject("My.App"); // -> returns a __ComObject, fine
        if (o == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not connect to My.App");
        Type t = o.GetType();
        object r = t.InvokeMember("XXX", BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public, null, o, null);  //--> returns a __ComObject, fine
        Interop_MyApp.IXXX xxx = r as Interop_MyApp.IXXX;    //----> here xxx is null?!
```

If I call t.GetProperties(), returns 0?? Where is the "XXX"?? Calling t.InvokeMember("XXX"...) succeeds!

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: COM is not an appropriate alternative for .NET remoting.  For one, you'll make the wrong assumptions, such as expecting Reflection to work.  Plenty of things you could do wrong to make the interface cast fail.  At least use (Interop_MyApp.IXXX)r so you'll get an half-decent exception.

Comment: Thanks. Got exception: Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IXXX'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{26E830E0-B0B5-4EAE-85F3-B2364654F47A}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: I added new int property XXX2 to MyApp which returns 111, and calling object r2 = t.InvokeMember("XXX2", BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public, null, o, null); will set r2 to 111. So getting the interface is the problem. Could be that some marshaling issue, but AFAIR it worked on other's PC.

Comment: Where did this interface type come from?  You cannot add a reference to the type library, the IDE will complain that you should not be using COM (it is right about that).  Declaring it yourself is a fail whale when you forget the [ComImport] and [Guid] attributes.  If you want to stick with COM anyway then using the *dynamic* keyword is highly advisable.

Comment: Interface comes from a tlb file, imported by tlbimp

Comment: E_NOINTERFACE is also generated if COM cannot figure out how to marshal the interface across the process boundary.  Did you forget to register the type library?  If you don't use the "Register for COM interop" IDE build option then running Regasm.exe with the /tlb option is required.

Comment: Man you are the winner, thanks!
Running regtlibv12.exe "...\....\...\xxx.tlb" solved the problem!
If you add your last comment as an answer, I can give you the solution.

Comment: I don't want to document regtlibv12.exe, it is only available by accident.

Comment: What other way we have? If I run the regasm Interop_MyApp.dll /tlb, i got error: RegAsm : error RA0000 : CLR assembly 'Interop_MyApp.dll' was imported from a type library and cannot be r
e-exported to a type library.  Make sure the type library from which the assembly was imported is registered.

Comment: You need to register the assembly that contains the original interface declaration.  The one that made it [ComVisible(true)]

Comment: There is no assembly. It's just a pure idl file. Tlb is generated from this idl by midl.

Comment: Hans, just answer it, so I can set this thread to resolved to help the others. If you don't want, I will answer it, not recommending (mentioning) the regtlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **Hans Passant** hints, I could solve the problem.
First I used a direct cast `(Interop_MyApp.IXXX)r` to get a more detailed error:

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'IXXX'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{26C830E0-B0B5-7EAE-85F3-B23455654F47A}' failed due to the following error: 
No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))
```

Then according to Hans' comment:

*E_NOINTERFACE is also generated if COM cannot figure out how to marshal the interface across the process boundary. Did you forget to register the type library? If you don't use the "Register for COM interop" IDE build option then running Regasm.exe with the /tlb option is required*

After registering the original tlb file, it worked like a charm.
The proper way to do it is the run Regasm on the assembly which contains the interface, however in my situation there is no assembly, only a pure idl interface file, and a type library created by midl.exe.
So not knowing other option, I used the regtlibv12.

Thanks all your helps